# jQuery mobile full screen iphone header position

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a problem with jQuery Mobile when I turn on full-screen mode on iPhone.

The header is a few pixels below the status bar.

Look at the picture, to see exactly what I mean: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/685/photozf.png/

I found a JavaScript solution that requires a fixed header, but I do not want to use a fixed header.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: You could increase the `padding-top` in the CSS, but this will look weird on other phones.

Comment: i know, but javascript solution works more elegantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that looks like a JQM dialog (ui-dialog) that is getting wrongly rendered. Note that the close button is missing (the whole topbar is cut off), the borders are missing, etc...

I would suggest first getting your dialog to render correctly (how do you open it?) and I am sure those problems will then go away (never had issues with dialogs on iOS).

Hope this helps